# Parallel.ForEach - System Out of Memory Exception

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

I have a problem with my website crawler as I get System Out of Memory Exception after it crawls something around 700 URLs. Memory usage is raising from the start and in one moment program just stops.

It is a console application written in C#.

I think the problem is that i instantiate 6 new objects at every foreach loop. Than i pass through them, get property values with reflection and create the final object that i use to DB save.

I expect .NET to destroy those object when not using them anymore but that is not the case. What are my options? Is BAckground Worker any better?

My code is something like this....

```
       Parallel.ForEach(Globals.Urls, url =>
        {

            progCtrl.indexIsSet = false;

            var urlHelper = url.Split(';')[1].TrimStart('\t');
           // var urlHelper = Globals.replaceGermanUmlauts(url.Split(';')[1].TrimStart('\t'));
            HtmlDocument htm = new HtmlDocument();

            try
            {
                Company comp0 = new Company();
                Company comp1 = new Company();
                Company comp2 = new Company();
                Company comp3 = new Company();
                Company comp4 = new Company();
                Company comp5 = new Company();
                Company comp6 = new Company();


//then I do some logic, add those companies to list and go further.
```

How to destory them? I have tried  making them IDisposable but that didn't help.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe the code is not not Disposing objects dealing with managed resources correctly? Or maybe the code is inadvertently keeping the objects strongly reachable (i.e. shoving them in a shared list) when they don't need to be?

Comment: When I set Company class to IDisposable it throws Memory exception from the start.

Comment: What happens if HtmlDocument is not created/used? I believe that uses the native IE web-browser through COM .. and I don't trust resources that live outside of .NET.

Comment: Complete logic of my application is based on HtmlDocument so not using it would be a very big workaround.

But as I Load cca 700 documents memory leak happens. You think it could be the cause and not those Company classes?

Comment: I'm not interested in solving the problem, only trying to help identify what in the code is causing the problem. Once that is better understood then the rest often falls into place.. it could also just be that there are too many Company objects floating about. If so, maybe a streaming approach could be used? "Adding those companies to a list" doesn't sound much like streaming :|