# Parallel.ForEach(...) System Out of Memory exception

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, garbage-collection

I've looked at [Parallel.ForEach - System Out of Memory Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22376084/parallel-foreach-system-out-of-memory-exception) regarding this issue but not much of a solution was given. I'm very new to using Parallel.ForEach, so I'm trying to figure out what's going on.

Diagnostic tools caps out at 1023 repeating (I understand this is an x86 to x64 arch restriction, but I wanted to offer the program in both formats.) I also don't feel like any program should ever meet that threshold. When I compile the program in x64, I sit around 1.1-1.4GB with MaxDegree . For sake of testing, I am running GC.Collection() at the end of each Parallel.ForEach iteration (I understand this isn't good practice, I'm just trying to troubleshoot at this point.)

Here's what I'm seeing:

[image]

Now if I try to use a Partitioner method, such as:

`var checkforfinished = Parallel.ForEach<ListViewItem>(Partitioner.Create(0,lstBackupUsers.Items.Count), lstBackupUsers.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>(), opts, name =>`

The I get an error of:

> "No overload for method 'ForEach' takes 4 arguments"

That's fine, I modify my `Parallel.ForEach` statement so it looks like this:

`var checkforfinished = Parallel.ForEach(Partitioner.Create(0,lstBackupUsers.Items.Count), lstBackupUsers.Items, opts, name =>` (I removed my  casts)

and then my ForEach method won't accept the statement because it wants me to explicitly tell it that it's addressing a listviewbox.items method.

I am so confused on what to do.

Do I create a Partitioner, and if I do, how do I make my `Parallel.ForEach` method understand how to address a listviewbox?

**update 1**

I want to try to give as many details as possible because this is just rough. I'm sure it's easy, I'm just overcomplicationg it by an nth degree.

I have my Parallel.ForEach(//) running in a background worker function. My DoWork process is over 300 lines (I'm not an expert in C#, I'm just putting things together for a program at work.)

Here are bullet points of its basic structure

- User clicks a "Start backup" button as seen in the screenshot
- Button begins a separate function that checks to see which method the user selected to grab a list of usernames from (LDAP or flat text file)
- That function then sends off a bgw_dowork() request
- Inside the DoWork request, it looks like a summary of:

  1. Check preliminary statements (bgw.cancellationpending for example)
  2. Move on to grabbing some settings from the configurationmanager.appsettings
  3. Begin the "complex" Parallel.ForEach command which Reads the listbox record rows and foreach row performs a very long list of commands to complete an operation for one user
  4. The entire program, especially bgw_dowork heavily uses Google's v3 Drive API to login as a user, grab a file as recorded by other functions that prepare the user directory to be backed up (separate functions which login as a user, record their files (and fileIds) and their directories/subdirectories) and the bgw_dowork performs a chunk of the actual download functionality, which then calls off to the other functions to finish moving the files after they have been downloaded.

The actual "code" I use is (and I promise it's not pretty...)

```
private void bgW_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
{
try
{
    txtFile.ReadOnly = true;
    btnStart.Text = "Cancel Backup";
    var appSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
    string checkreplace = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["checkreplace"];

    string userfile = txtFile.Text;
    int counter = 0;
    int arraycount = 0;

    if (bgW.CancellationPending)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        stripLabel.Text = "Operation was canceled!";
    }
    else
    {
        for (int z = 0; z >= counter; z++)
        {
            if (bgW.CancellationPending)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                stripLabel.Text = "Operation was canceled!";
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                double totalresource = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["multithread"]);
                totalresource = (totalresource / 100);
                //var opts = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((Environment.ProcessorCount * totalresource) * 1.0)) };
                var opts = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2 };
                var part = Partitioner.Create(1, 100);
                //foreach (ListViewItem name in lstBackupUsers.Items)
                var checkforfinished = Parallel.ForEach(lstBackupUsers.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>(), name =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string names = name.SubItems[0].Text;
                        lstBackupUsers.Items[arraycount].Selected = true;
                        lstBackupUsers.Items[arraycount].BackColor = Color.CornflowerBlue;
                        arraycount++;
                        stripLabel.Text = "";
                        Console.WriteLine("Selecting user: " + names.ToString());
                        txtLog.Text += "Selecting user: " + names.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
                        txtCurrentUser.Text = names.ToString();
                            // Define parameters of request.
                            string user = names.ToString();

                            // Check if directory exists, create if not.
                            string savelocation = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["savelocation"] + user + "\\";

                        if (File.Exists(savelocation + ".deltalog.tok"))
                            File.Delete(savelocation + ".deltalog.tok");
                        FileInfo testdir = new FileInfo(savelocation);
                        testdir.Directory.Create();
                        string savedStartPageToken = "";
                        var start = CreateService.BuildService(user).Changes.GetStartPageToken().Execute();

                            // This token is set by Google, it defines changes made and
                            // increments the token value automatically. 
                            // The following reads the current token file (if it exists)
                            if (File.Exists(savelocation + ".currenttoken.tok"))
                        {
                            StreamReader curtokenfile = new StreamReader(savelocation + ".currenttoken.tok");
                            savedStartPageToken = curtokenfile.ReadLine().ToString();
                            curtokenfile.Dispose();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                // Token record didn't exist. Create a generic file, start at "1st" token
                                // In reality, I have no idea what token to start at, but 1 seems to be safe.
                                Console.Write("Creating new token file.\n");
                                //txtLog.Text += ("Creating new token file.\n" + Environment.NewLine);
                                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(savelocation + ".currenttoken.tok");
                            sw.Write(1);
                            sw.Dispose();
                            savedStartPageToken = "1";
                        }
                        string pageToken = savedStartPageToken;
                        int gtoken = int.Parse(start.StartPageTokenValue);
                        int mytoken = int.Parse(savedStartPageToken);
                        txtPrevToken.Text = pageToken.ToString();
                        txtCurrentToken.Text = gtoken.ToString();
                        if (gtoken <= 10)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Nothing to save!\n");
                                //txtLog.Text += ("User has nothing to save!" + Environment.NewLine);
                            }
                        else
                        {
                            if (pageToken == start.StartPageTokenValue)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("No file changes found for " + user + "\n");
                                    //txtLog.Text += ("No file changes found! Please wait while I tidy up." + Environment.NewLine);
                                }
                            else
                            {
                                    // .deltalog.tok is where we will place our records for changed files
                                    Console.WriteLine("Changes detected. Making notes while we go through these.");
                                lblProgresslbl.Text = "Scanning Drive directory.";

                                    // Damnit Google, why did you change how the change fields work?
                                    if (savedStartPageToken == "1")
                                {
                                    statusStripLabel1.Text = "Recording folder list ...";
                                    txtLog.Text = "Recording folder list ..." + Environment.NewLine;
                                    exfunctions.RecordFolderList(savedStartPageToken, pageToken, user, savelocation);
                                    statusStripLabel1.Text = "Recording new/changed files ... This may take a bit!";
                                    txtLog.Text += Environment.NewLine + "Recording new/changed list for: " + user;
                                    exfunctions.ChangesFileList(savedStartPageToken, pageToken, user, savelocation);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                        //proUserclass = proUser;
                                        statusStripLabel1.Text = "Recording new/changed files ... This may take a bit!";
                                    txtLog.Text += Environment.NewLine + "Recording new/changed list for: " + user + Environment.NewLine;
                                    exfunctions.ChangesFileList(savedStartPageToken, pageToken, user, savelocation);
                                }

                                    // Get all our files for the user. Max page size is 1k
                                    // after that, we have to use Google's next page token
                                    // to let us get more files.
                                    StreamWriter logFile = new StreamWriter(savelocation + ".recent.log");
                                string[] deltafiles = File.ReadAllLines(savelocation + ".deltalog.tok");

                                int totalfiles = deltafiles.Count();
                                int cnttototal = 0;
                                Console.WriteLine("\nFiles to backup:\n");
                                if (deltafiles == null)
                                {
                                    return;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    double damn = ((gtoken - double.Parse(txtPrevToken.Text)));
                                    damn = Math.Round((damn / totalfiles));
                                    if (damn <= 0)
                                        damn = 1;
                                    foreach (var file in deltafiles)
                                    {
                                        try
                                        {
                                            if (bgW.CancellationPending)
                                            {
                                                stripLabel.Text = "Backup canceled!";
                                                e.Cancel = true;
                                                break;
                                            }
                                            DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
                                            string[] foldervalues = File.ReadAllLines(savelocation + "folderlog.txt");

                                            cnttototal++;
                                            bgW.ReportProgress(cnttototal);
                                            proUser.Maximum = int.Parse(txtCurrentToken.Text);
                                            stripLabel.Text = "File " + cnttototal + " of " + totalfiles;
                                            double? mathisfun;
                                            mathisfun = ((100 * cnttototal) / totalfiles);
                                            if (mathisfun <= 0)
                                                mathisfun = 1;
                                            double mathToken = double.Parse(txtPrevToken.Text);
                                            mathToken = Math.Round((damn + mathToken));
                                                // Bring our token up to date for next run
                                                txtPrevToken.Text = mathToken.ToString();
                                            File.WriteAllText(savelocation + ".currenttoken.tok", mathToken.ToString());
                                            int proval = int.Parse(txtPrevToken.Text);
                                            int nowval = int.Parse(txtCurrentToken.Text);
                                            if (proval >= nowval)
                                                proval = nowval;
                                            proUser.Value = (proval);
                                            lblProgresslbl.Text = ("Current progress: " + mathisfun.ToString() + "% completed.");
                                                // Our file is a CSV. Column 1 = file ID, Column 2 = File name
                                                var values = file.Split(',');
                                            string fileId = values[0];
                                            string fileName = values[1];
                                            string mimetype = values[2];
                                            mimetype = mimetype.Replace(",", "_");
                                            string folder = values[3];
                                            string ext = null;

                                            int folderfilelen = foldervalues.Count();

                                            fileName = GetSafeFilename(fileName);

                                            Console.WriteLine("Filename: " + values[1]);
                                            logFile.WriteLine("ID: " + values[0] + " - Filename: " + values[1]);
                                            logFile.Flush();


                                                // Things get sloppy here. The reason we're checking MimeTypes
                                                // is because we have to export the files from Google's format
                                                // to a format that is readable by a desktop computer program
                                                // So for example, the google-apps.spreadsheet will become an MS Excel file.
                                                switch (mimetype)
                                            {
 (switch statement here removed due to body length issues for this post.)
                                            }

                                            if (ext.Contains(".doc") || ext.Contains(".xls"))
                                            {
                                                string whatami = null;
                                                if (ext.Contains(".xls"))
                                                {
                                                    whatami = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                                                }
                                                else if (ext.Contains(".doc"))
                                                {
                                                    whatami = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
                                                }
                                                else if (ext.Contains(".ppt"))
                                                {
                                                    whatami = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation";
                                                }
                                                if (fileName.Contains(".mov") || ext == ".ggl" || fileName.Contains(".mp4"))
                                                {
                                                    txtLog.Text += Environment.NewLine + "Skipping file.";
                                                    return;
                                                }

                                                var requestfileid = CreateService.BuildService(user).Files.Export(fileId, whatami);
                                                statusStripLabel1.Text = (savelocation + fileName + ext);
                                                txtCurrentUser.Text = user;
                                                string dest1 = Path.Combine(savelocation, fileName + ext);
                                                var stream1 = new System.IO.FileStream(dest1, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
                                                scrolltobtm();
                                                requestfileid.MediaDownloader.ProgressChanged +=
                                                            (IDownloadProgress progress) =>
                                                            {
                                                                switch (progress.Status)
                                                                {
                                                                    case DownloadStatus.Downloading:
                                                                        {
                                                                            Console.WriteLine(progress.BytesDownloaded);
                                                                            logFile.WriteLine("Downloading: " + progress.BytesDownloaded);
                                                                            txtLog.Text += ("Downloading ... " + progress.BytesDownloaded + Environment.NewLine);
                                                                            scrolltobtm();
                                                                            logFile.Flush();
                                                                            break;
                                                                        }
                                                                    case DownloadStatus.Completed:
                                                                        {
                                                                            Console.WriteLine("Download complete.");
                                                                            logFile.WriteLine("[" + user + "] Download complete for: " + requestfileid.ToString());
                                                                            txtLog.Text += ("[" + user + "] Download complete for: " + fileName + Environment.NewLine);
                                                                            logFile.Flush();

                                                                            break;
                                                                        }
                                                                    case DownloadStatus.Failed:
                                                                        {
                                                                            Console.WriteLine("Download failed.");
                                                                            logFile.WriteLine("Download failed.");
                                                                            logFile.Flush();
                                                                            break;
                                                                        }
                                                                }
                                                            };
                                                scrolltobtm();
                                                GC.Collect();
                                                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                                                requestfileid.Download(stream1);
                                                stream1.Close();
                                                stream1.Dispose();
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                scrolltobtm();
                                                var requestfileid = CreateService.BuildService(user).Files.Get(fileId);
                                                    //Generate the name of the file, and create it as such on the local filesystem.
                                                    statusStripLabel1.Text = (savelocation + fileName + ext);
                                                string dest1 = Path.Combine(savelocation, fileName + ext);
                                                var stream1 = new System.IO.FileStream(dest1, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
                                                requestfileid.MediaDownloader.ProgressChanged +=
                                                            (IDownloadProgress progress) =>
                                                            {
                                                                switch (progress.Status)
                                                                {
                                                                    case DownloadStatus.Downloading:
                                                                        {
                                                                            Console.WriteLine(progress.BytesDownloaded);
                                                                            logFile.WriteLine("Downloading: " + progress.BytesDownloaded);
                                                                            txtLog.Text += ("Downloading ... " + progress.BytesDownloaded + Environment.NewLine);
                                                                            scrolltobtm();
                                                                            logFile.Flush();
                                                                            break;
                                                                        }
                                                                    case DownloadStatus.Completed:
                                                                        {
                                                                            Console.WriteLine("Download complete.");
                                                                            logFile.WriteLine("Download complete for: " + requestfileid.ToString());
                                                                            txtLog.Text += (Environment.NewLine + "[" + user + "] Download complete for: " + fileName + Environment.NewLine);
                                                                            logFile.Flush();
                                                                            break;
                                                                        }
                                                                    case DownloadStatus.Failed:
                                                                        {

                                                                            Console.WriteLine("Download failed.");
                                                                            logFile.WriteLine("Download failed.");
                                                                            logFile.Flush();
                                                                            break;
                                                                        }
                                                                }
                                                            };
                                                scrolltobtm();
                                                GC.Collect();
                                                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                                                requestfileid.Download(stream1);
                                                stream1.Close();
                                                stream1.Dispose();

                                            }
                                        }
                                        catch (Google.GoogleApiException ex)
                                        {
                                            Console.Write("\nInfo: ---> " + ex.Message.ToString() + "\n");
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                exfunctions.MoveFiles(savelocation);
                                Console.WriteLine("\n\n\tBackup completed for selected user!");
                                txtLog.Text += ("\n\nBackup completed for selected user.\n\n");
                                statusStripLabel1.Text = "";

                                //logFile.Close();
                                //logFile.Dispose();

                            }

                        }

                    }
                    catch (Google.GoogleApiException ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Info: " + ex.Message.ToString());
                    }
                }
                );
                if (checkforfinished.IsCompleted == true)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Parallel.ForEach() Finished!");
                    Console.WriteLine("Parallel.ForEach() Finished!");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Parallel.ForEach() not completed!");
                    Console.WriteLine("Parallel.ForEach() not completed!");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Google.GoogleApiException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Info: " + ex.Message.ToString());
}
}
}
```

You can see where I initiate the Parallel.ForEach(...) and then see what it is in charge of doing. It's a lot, and I understand it's not pretty, so I appreciate constructive criticism.

Comment: There is not enough information here to help you resolve the `OutOfMemory` issue. With regards to your other 2 syntax error issue, which overload are you trying to use, there are way too many overloads of these available to guess here. Checkout [Parallel.ForEach overloads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Partitioner.Create overloads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.partitioner_methods(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to elaborate a bit more, but I'm not exactly sure what it is I can explain to be honest. I'll update my original post with some more details.

Comment: You need to provide details on what exactly are you trying to do within the `Action` block of your `Parallel.ForEach`

Comment: I hope the update I did will allow a bigger picture to help figure out what is going on with the memory usage. Thank you again.

Comment: You should check up on http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to understand how to provide code for your problem

Comment: Ok. I'll close this question then. Thanks.